# remove ? char from my url for use custom api

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 6 with custom api, I would like to change the URL 
from 
http://my.domain.com/test?key1=5&key2=ABC
to this 
http://my.domain.com/test/key1=5&key2=ABC

How can I remove the "?" char between url and first parameter

```
$endpoint = "http://my.domain.com/test";
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$key1= 5;
$key2= ABC;

$response = $client->request('GET', $endpoint, ['query' => [
    'key1' => $key1,
    'kei2' => $key2

]]);
```

Comment: Have your tried str_replace?

Comment: I would suggest looking into the PHP function parse_url

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<?php
echo str_replace("?","/","http://my.domain.com/test.php?key1=5&key2=ABC");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can go with...

1. `preg_replace` Slower
2. `str_replace`

This practice is `preg_replace`

```
$uri = 'http://my.domain.com/test.php?key1=5&key2=ABC';
$uri = preg_replace('/[?]/', '/', $uri);
var_dump($uri);
//Output http://my.domain.com/test.php/key1=5&key2=ABC
```

`preg_replace` is slower than `str_replace`

Now this practice is `str_replace`

`$uri = 'http://my.domain.com/test.php?key1=5&key2=ABC';
 $uri = str_replace(['?'],['/'],$uri);
 var_dump($uri);
 //Output http://my.domain.com/test.php/key1=5&key2=ABC`

`str_replace` is faster than `preg_replace`

If you want to replace more than one string then use comma after `['?','key']`

`$uri = str_replace(['?','key'],['/'],$uri);`

And if you want to second string with any other string then `['?','key'], ['/', 'element']`

`$uri = str_replace(['?','key'], ['/', 'element'],$uri);`

What `str_replace` do is it replaces the specific input string/strings and will only replace the strings.

Now what `preg_replace` do is it uses regular expression to match your result.

Just a side note `preg_match`, `preg_match_all` and `preg_replace` and many more php `preg` functions are related.

Answer (score 0):

You can split URL into parts and put it together in the custom order.

```
$expectedUrl = 'http://my.domain.com/test/key1=5&key2=ABC';

$urlParts = parse_url('http://my.domain.com/test?key1=5&key2=ABC');
$resultUrl = $urlParts['scheme'] . '://' . $urlParts['host'] . $urlParts['path'] . '/' . $urlParts['query'];

var_dump(
    $resultUrl === $expectedUrl
);
```